# Show webView if count x number

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, uiwebview

I'm working on a crosswords app in Swift and I want to show a certain webView only when it matches a certain condition.

Here's my snippet:

```
if (completedPuzzles.count == 25) {
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://he8eymyf1s6.typeform.com/to/iEKxw8gl")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        backButton()
        webView.load(myRequest)                
    }
```

Now I show the webView when the number of completed puzzles counts as 25 but it seems that for the people who already completed 25 before this update, they are ignored.

How can I make sure that people see the webView even if they already completed 25+ before the update and not ignore it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `>= 25` instead of `== 25` and what do you mean with "count from zero"? Is anything persisted when the app is closed, what exactly are you counting?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it doesn't count from zero, but it gets ignored for people who already completed 25 of those puzzles.
Regarding your comment, adding >= should solve it? If someone completed, let's say, 30 and then it completes +1 it will show the webView?

Comment: Not sure why you ask me if it should work but yes >= is the right operator for finding  users that has completed 25 or more crosswords.

Comment: My main concern is that if someone already completed 25 crosswords before the code update will it show the webView at 26?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what your main concern means. There seems to be a lot  to this that you aren't telling us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand it correctly you want to do it every time a user played 25 games if that is true you can do something like this

```
var var numberOfWebpagesShown = 0
if (completedPuzzles.count % 25 == 0 || numberOfWebpagesShown < completedPuzzles.count / 25  ) {
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    let myURL = URL(string:"https://he8eymyf1s6.typeform.com/to/iEKxw8gl")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    backButton()
    webView.load(myRequest)                
}
```

this will show the webview everytime the completedPuzzles.count is dividable by 25 like 25, 50, 75 and so on. and do it if a user havent been shown a webpage for their current stage

Comment: Something along these lines, but my main question is, if let's say someone already completed  25 games before this code update, then I do not want to wait until he reaches 50 to show the webView again. I want to show it at 26 or 51, or 76. Hope you get my point...

Comment: Basically, if he already completed 25 show it at 26, if he completed 26 show it at 27 and so on...

Comment: does this new edit fix it for you ?

Comment: Will have to check it but it seems to be fine, Thanks